# Derivation of the advection equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

Is there a good derivation of the advection equation available online? By that I mean the equation

$\partial_t u = -\nabla( \vec{v} u)$

I know a good explanation for the one-dimensional case $\partial_t u = -v\, \partial_x u$ (presumably in the case that the gas is incompressible). Is there a derivation for the three-dimensional case available?